# How to get the properties when a slide is clicked in swiperjs without jquery

Tags: javascript, reactjs, swiper.js

I am trying to get the values of a specific card when it is clicked in swiperJS but am not finding in the documentation if it is possible to do so.

Hoping to not resort to wrapping each slide in a label and input button.

My code here:

```
                    <Swiper
                        slidesPerView={'auto'}
                        spaceBetween={200}
                        centeredSlides={true}
                        pagination={{
                            "clickable": true
                        }}>
                        {Cards.map((card, idx) => {
                            return (
                                <div className="row" style={{ display: 'inline-block' }}>
                                    <div className="col-12 swiper-container">
                                        <SwiperSlide>
                                            <Cards
                                                number={card.number}
                                                name={card.name}
                                                expiry={card.expiry}
                                                cvc={card.cvc}
                                            // focused={focus}
                                            />
                                        </SwiperSlide>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            )
                        })}
                    </Swiper>
```

Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at swiper's react [source code](https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/blob/master/src/react/swiper-slide.js) it seems like `SwiperSlide` renders by default into a `div` node . This node can receive a `onClick` prop, which should execute whatever function you want. That would look something like this:

```
<SwiperSlide onClick={()=> console.log(card.name)}>
  // ...
</SwiperSlide>
```

If for some reason that doesn't work either, consider adding the `onClick` to a div already wrapping the slide (for example `div.col-12.swiper-container`)